# Correct way to do dependency management in Angular 2 projects

Tags: angular

I would like to get some advice on the most appropriate way to do dependency management for external client side libraries with Angular 2.

Previously I have used Bower with Angular 1.x, but it appears a number of sources have suggested that this is not a good idea as it doesn't work well with TypeScript and ES6.

Ultimately I want to be able to manage dependencies for things like jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap in my Angular app without having to hard code a bunch of stuff directly with  tags.

The Angular 2 documentation seems to be completely silent on this matter. The only thing that is clear is that it uses SystemJS as a module loader, but this doesn't solve the dependency management side of things.

I would really appreciate it if I could be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Can you accept as a correct answer or if there is some point of the question that I don't cover, let me now.

Answer (score 1):

Start a project with angular-CLI and follow [this documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs//).

Those are basic steps to adding dependency into a project.

- Installing package with npm and install typings
- Adding package file location into the angular-cli configuration to bundling.
- Making configuration of systemjs as mapping location of file and  package configuration in systemjs as default file format and main file setting (it can change as main.js, index.js, jquery.js, d3.js)
- Now, you can import your 3-party package

Comment: This is a useful start, which is why I have up voted it. But this really only works with code libraries and it seems like a fairly convoluted way to handle it.  The problem is with dependencies like Bootstrap I also need to load in CSS, fonts and other assets. Ideally I would want to customise it and compile a LESS or SASS file to create the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: I'm also interested in this issue. Have you made any further progress by any chance @JamesXabregas? I think the solution needs to be ongoing to support the introduction new libraries, not only helpful when creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

Best angular2 kick starter I have come across

https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

How to add external libraries just follow this link
https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/wiki/Add-external-dependency